# Struct with an pointer to an Interface mock error

Tags: go, testing, gomock

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
    "testing"
)

type Talker interface {
    talk() string
}

type Person struct {
    moth *Talker
}

func (p *Person) speak() string {
    return (*p.moth).talk()
}

func TestPerson(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    mockTalker := NewMockTalker(ctl)

    person := Person{moth: mockTalker}
}
```

Assuming that I have already created a mock for Talker interface using mockgen.

I am getting error when I am creating `Person{moth: mockTalker}`. I am not able to pass `mockTalker`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't user pointer interface. Essentially interface is pointer

```
type Person struct {
    moth Talker
}
```

Normally, if function want return `interface`, it's will return new struct by pointer.

```
import "fmt"

type I interface {
    M()
}

type S struct {
}

func (s *S) M() {
    fmt.Println("M")
}

func NewI() I {
    return &S{}
}

func main() {
    i := NewI()
    i.M()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Person` struct the moth field is `*Talker` type. It is a pointer type of `Talker` interface. `NewMockTalker(ctl)` returns  `Talker` type mock implementation.

You can do two things to fix this.

1. Change the `Person`'s moth field's type to `Talker`.

```
type Person struct {
    moth Talker
}
```

or

2. pass pointer reference of `mockTalker` to the `person` initialization`

```
person := Person{moth: &mockTalker}
```